# d3 grid lines, have done some research but still stuck

Tags: javascript, d3.js, grid

I am teaching myself d3. I have read through the tutorials by Scott Murray and I am reading through D3 Tips and Tricks and I have looked through stackoverflow. I read "Proper Way to Draw Gridlines, among others. When I have a question my answer is usually here. But I am stuck, it is definitely due to my inexperience, and I have a fiddle:

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9uDMc/)

Here is the snippet I copied from "Proper Way to Draw Gridlines":

```
    svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(yScale.ticks())
   .enter()
    .append("circle")
       .attr("x1", margin.right)
       .attr("x2", width)   
       .attr("y1", function(d){ 
        return yScale(d[2]);
            })
       .attr("y2", function(d){ 
        return yScale(d[2]);
        })
       .attr("fill", "none")
       .attr("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
       .attr("stroke", "black")
       .attr("stroke-width", "1px");
```

I would love to draw grid lines across the y axis AND the x axis, but I figured I'd do one thing at a time.

I've tried using .tickSize(), I've created the make_y_axis function, but I am missing something. All advice (or a shove in the right direction) is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use d3.svg.axis().scale() to tie up the grid to your coordinates. I drew a [quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/9uDMc/3/) based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/9uDMc/3/

[image]

The gist is to use the existing scales, x and y, and to use ticks as grid. Since yAxis and xAxis are already defined we can just re-use them. Here is the relevant code:

```
//Draw a grid
var yAxisGrid = yAxis
  .tickSize(width, 0)
  .tickFormat("")
  .orient("right")

var xAxisGrid = xAxis
  .tickSize(-height, 0)
  .tickFormat("")
  .orient("top")

svg.append("g")
  .classed('y', true)
  .classed('axis', true)
  .call(yAxisGrid)

svg.append("g")
  .classed('x', true)
  .classed('axis', true)
  .call(xAxisGrid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is -- it works pretty much by copying and pasting the code you've quoted into your jsfiddle. I've added the other grid lines as well and used `.range()` of the scales to determine the length of each line. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9uDMc/1/).

Comment: Ah ha! The problem was I did not understand parts of the code I copied. Thank you!